# How to react to a ControlTemplate property change on the child ContentView of a ContentPage?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have a ContentView on my page which consumes its content from a ControlTemplate defined as static resource, based on the state of a boolean property from the bound ViewModel, using DataTriggers:

```
   <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="template1">
     <local:AnotherContentView />
     <!-- Here AnotherContentView needs to have one of its method called. -->
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="template2">
    </ControlTemplate>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

  <ContentView x:Name="templatedView" >
    <ContentView.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger TargetType="ContentView" Binding="{Binding BoolValueFromViewModel}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource template1}"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger TargetType="ContentView" Binding="{Binding BoolValueFromViewModel}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource template2}"/>
      </DataTrigger>
    </ContentView.Triggers>
  </ContentView>
```

-> On line 3 you can see AnotherContentView, which is a custom control that needs to have one of its method called (for UI update purpose) on the event that it is appearing on the page. I have tried using OnApplyTemplate on both ContentPage's and ContentView's code, and OnAppearing on ContentView's code but without success.

Hopefully this approach is correct and I am just missing something ? Thanks a lot for any input

**EDIT:** "AnotherContentView needs to have one of its method called" -> why? Because AnotherContentView contains a GraphicsView element which is invalidated every x milliseconds and therefore re-drawn. What I am trying to implement is simply rendering a gauge that decreases over time.

That method that handles the update of the GraphicsView looks like this:

```
public async Task LoopGaugeDrawing()
{
    do
    {
        _progressGauge.TargetTime = Duration;
        _progressGauge.ElapsedTime = Duration.Subtract(RemainingTime);

        ProgressView.Invalidate();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Constants.TimerTickMilliseconds));
    }
    while (!ConditionFromViewModel);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Here AnotherContentView needs to have one of its method called". You cannot directly make method calls from XAML. Please elaborate on your question and explain what exactly you're trying to achieve. What is your goal?

Comment: I have edited my question to provide more information about what I am trying to achieve, I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using the following method in the ContentView object does what I am trying to achieve, still not sure if my approach is correct though.

```
protected async override void OnParentSet()
{
    base.OnParentSet();

    await LoopGaugeDrawing();
}
```